# import 'package:using_tabs/tabs/first.dart'; >> Target of URI doesn't exist

Tags: dart, flutter, importerror

`import 'package:using_tabs/tabs/first.dart';`

This is from an example code here >> https://github.com/nisrulz/flutter-examples/blob/master/using_tabs/lib/main.dart

noob question. If I try to reuse the code and replace **using_tabs** with my project name, and create a file **first.dart** in a folder **tabs** the IDE is throwing an error, **Target of URI doesn't exist**

I know I could fix it by changing it to something like

```
import './ThirdTab.dart' as third_tab;
```

But I'm interested in understanding the **package** syntax. Documentation didn't help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the package-style imports for all files under your project's `lib/` directory.  The path is simply the relative path from `lib/` (The `lib/` directory itself is omitted) to the file.  After adding a new package-style import you may need to run `flutter packages get`, or your IDE may handle this automatically.

In a `pubspec.yaml` give your project a name.

```
name: my_project
```

And with a directory structure like the following

```
 pubspec.yaml
 lib/
 ├── main.dart
 ├── fizz.dart
 ├── foo/
 │   ├── bar.dart
 │   ├── foo.dart
```

Then inside of `main.dart` you can import using the `package:` style like the following:

```
import 'package:my_project/fizz.dart';
import 'package:my_project/foo/bar.dart';
```

Lastly, if you use and IDE like Intellij, Android Studio, or Visual Studio Code you can use the auto import feature by using an identifier from an unimported library and then using the contextual action to add an import.  This action will add a package-style import to your current library.

Comment: Thanks, going by your example, I had **foo* under the main project directory, instead of in **lib**